# VB.net ConnectionStrings object reference

Tags: xml, vb.net, connection-string, config

when connecting i get an error:
**object reference not set to instance of an object**

Form1

```
Dim c As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CON").ConnectionString
Dim con As New MySqlConnection(c)
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="CON" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=DATABASE_;Uid=user;Pwd=pass" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I have no idea how to fix this issue...

This works

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=DATABASE_;Uid=user;Pwd=pass")
```

Ultimately i am trying to protect my connection string.

Debug output:
**A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Loader.exe**
This is saying that System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CON").ConnectionString is returning null

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've differents names in app.config and code.

```
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
Dim cs As String = ConnectionStrings("CON").ConnectionString
```

**EDIT**

The problem was a bad app.config setup file. Please read the comments.

Comment: It seems that ConnectionStrings("CON").ConnectionString is returning null

Comment: @user3466723 Are you loading the correct app.config? Check if it is debug or release. Check other app.config setting

Comment: enlighten me, i might not be. I am calling the connectionString directly.

Comment: @user3466723 Run directly the .exe (not from VS). In the same folder the .exe.config file should be. Open that file and check if the string connection is there.

Comment: its not <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: how do i load my config?

Comment: Thank you this got me on the right track :) i was trying to follow a C++ guide for VB.net :) i fixed it now thanks to you :)